# Azure DevOps keeps asking for credentials on Safari 17

Tags: azure-devops, safari

I'm having a problem since the last update of Safari to version 17. Azure DevOps ask for my credentials every time I click on anything.

On the previous versions of Safari there was an alternative which is to turn off the parameter **NSURLSession WebSocket** on Experimental features (source : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693788), but after the update Experimental Features are no longer available.

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Azure DevOps service or Azure DevOps On-prem server?  Does this issue only exists in Safari 17? When you use other Browsers(e.g. Chrome, Edge), will it work as expected?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT It's on-prem server. It's okay for Firefox. There was a problem with Safari before but the Experimental Features were available so it was possible to bypass this but after the update of version 17 it's no longer available.
Because of some configurations and restrictions, I don't have the choice to switch to another browser, but for now I have to do it for Azure Devops only.

Comment: Can you check if there are any extensions installed in Safari related to Password?

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255159008. NSURLSession WebSocket is now always on. I imagine some of the possible ways to fix would be:
- a fix in ADO2022
- a plugin in Safari to allow us to turn it off

our temp. fix is to use a different browser.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT No extensions are installed, and saving credentials on Safari was working in previous updates with WebSocket on but not anymore.

Comment: @NicolasW Extensions are kind of complicated to add because of security filters and risks. I've tried the token method but it's no longer working in this update

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT would you by any chance know of any workaround ? is this something MSFT is working on ? ty

Comment: @NicolasW For now there seems to be no solution, I've tried changing the config file for Safari but all tries failed. Microsoft in not the source of this problem, it's Apple and the changes made in their privacy and security policies, for for now let's just hope that they'll give us back the experimental features on Developer Mode at least ...